# Taxonomy pages, stop them indexing or being generated?

Tags: taxonomy

Not sure if anyone can help / advise on the following:

Just looking into WordPress pages that are automatically generated, like taxonomy pages. We have seen search results come up before the actual page they refer to, which is confusing for a site visitor.

A result with say: www.youdomain.com/?s=taxonomy&ccp=true

Is there any way to tell search engines to ignore these and ask them to refer to the actual page in full, not these excerpts?

Thanks - PJ

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install the [Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) then in your wp-admin go to SEO -> Titles & Meta -> Taxonomies and click 'no index, follow' next to the ones you don't wish to be indexed.

Edit: Sorry, slightly confused. Your taxonomy pages have two urls? is that it?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

We already use the SEO Ultimate plugin, so really don't want to load the site with another SEO plugin if at all possible.

SEO Ultimate comes with many other features we like to use, over the Yoast version.

Any other ideas, perhaps at .htaccess level we could employ?

Thanks - PJ